# accessing a specific point of a vector with an iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am trying to figure out the best way of accessing a position in a vector using an iterator. I'm aware iterators behave like pointers, so this is the only method I came up with. I would like to know if there's a better or just a different way. Here's the code:

```
   //This is a pointer to a vector of the class Particle BTW. vector < Particle > *particleList;
   vector<Particle>::iterator it = particleList->begin();
   // I assign a specific position outside the loop to a new iterator that won't be affected
   vector<Particle>::iterator it2 = particleList->begin() + 3;
   for( it; it != particleList->end(); it++){


    it->draw();
    //I'm interested in the velocity of this element in particular
    cout << it2->vel << endl;
}
```

Thanks,

M

Comment: Its not the only way. Things like [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) , [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), and [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) are made for this specific purpose.

Comment: They also have the added benefit of just doing "the right thing" with the iterator depending on its type `ate::advance` for instance, requires a bi-directional iterator or above. For a random-access iterator it will make the jump in constant-time, while a bi-directional will make it in O(N) time, and it just does the right thing for the given iterator type. Make it a habit to use them (at least for leaps larger than 1).

Comment: Random access iterators have pretty much the same interface as pointers (vector iterators are often implemented as pointers) and support operator[] so you can also do vec.begin()[i]

Comment: @WhozCraig: Or simply use operator `+` when you expect random access iterators so that compiler will stop you in case of non-random iterators. I prefer to know the exact asymptotic complexity of my algorithm.

Comment: That's right Matthew, though I thought in terms of better practice, it is better to use iterators, unless you are initiating the vector, you go for the operator

Comment: @CR So do I, and when I change a core container to one that doesn't support random-access iterator types (and I just changed it, so i know it doesn't and better know the algorithm complexity therein), I don't want to have to leap around hundreds of places in my code to change `it+1` to something that works. To each their own.

Comment: I'm trying to use advance but it does not seem to work. I'm trying this:     vector<Particle>::iterator it = particleList->begin();
    for( it; it != particleList->end(); it++){       
        it->draw();
        advance(it, 3);
        
        cout << it->vel <<endl;
        
        
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
for (auto i = particleList->begin(); i < particleList->begin(); ++i) {
  i->draw();
  std::cout << (i+3)->vel << "\n";
}
```

Note, there is no reason to use `std::endl`, `std::endl` has an implicit flush which lowers performance when outputting to say a log file, and when outputting to console it is already line buffered meaning that a line ending will already flush.

Note 2, you can only use `+` with `i` since `i` is a random access iterator because `particleList` is a `std::vector`, if you change say `particleList` to a `std::list` then the iterator will be a bidirectional iterator instead of a random access iterator and you will not be able to use `+` in that case you would need to use `std::advance` like WhozCraig mentioned, but do so on a copy like so:

```
for (auto i = particleList->begin(); i < particleList->begin(); ++i) {
  i->draw();
  auto i2 = i;
  std::advance(i2, 3)
  std::cout << i2->vel << "\n";
}
```

Though personally, in this case I would just iterate with two iterators instead of `std::advance` since `std::advance` is linear in time. Do something like:

```
auto i = particleList->begin();
auto i2 = particleList->begin();
std::advance(i2, 3);
for (; i < particleList->end(); ++i, ++i2) {
  i->draw();
  std::cout << i2->vel << "\n";
}
```

Note 3: `(i+3)` and `i2` will run off the end of your list (vector), so do something smart there.